# Toggling the window visibility instantiates new window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a modularized application with Prism. A simple window (shell) is displayed. The shell contains a taskbar icon that invokes a command to toggle windows visibility. Clicking the TaskbarIcon creates a new instance of my shell instead of toggling the visibility of the original one. Does someone know why my code does not invoke the method on first shell?

**My Bootstrapper**

```
 protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        var shell = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(Shell), typeof(Shell), true);
        return shell;

    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {

        var mainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
        var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
        mainWindow.Show();
}
```

**My taskbarIcon**

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon
            Name="ToolbarIcon"
          IconSource="/Resources/images/icon.ico"
          ToolTipText="Some text" 
            LeftClickCommand="{StaticResource ShowWindowCommand}"/>
```

**ShowWindowCommand**

```
    public class ShowWindowCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>().toggleVisibility();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

**Shell.togglingVisibility()**

```
public void toggleVisibility()
    {
        if (this.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible){
            this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;                
        }
        else
        {
            this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        }  
    }
```

Comment: I use now  
"((Shell)Application.Current.MainWindow).toggleVisibility();"
in my Command class. It works like a charm but nevertheless I would like to know the error with the first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not always using the singleton shell.

In `CreateShell` you first get *a* shell instance, then register the shell as singleton. Later on in `ShowWindowCommand.Execute` you get the singleton instance, which is not the same as the non-singleton instance you resolved before. How should the container know that the first resolved instance will later on be used as a singleton? You might even have had resolved multiple instances before registering as a singleton...

Comment: You are right, it made no sense in any way to create a shell instance before register another one as singleton... I have removed the "var shell =..." statement and return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>() after register it. Now it works. Thank you!